# Terraform - Multi Loops or Maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am creating few public subnets, private subnets, igw, nat, route_tables, and route_table entry in AWS using terraform. Below is the number of resources I am creating.

terraform.tfvars

```
vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
public_subnet_count = 6
public_subnets_cidr  = ["10.0.1.0/24","10.0.2.0/24","10.0.3.0/24","10.0.4.0/24","10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
availability_zones = ["us-east-2a", "us-east-2b","us-east-2c","us-east-2d"]
```

```
resources.tf

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.vpc_cidr
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}-vpc"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  count                   = var.public_subnet_count
  cidr_block              = "${element(var.public_subnets_cidr, count.index)}"
  availability_zone       = length(var.availability_zones) > 1 ? var.availability_zones[count.index % length(var.availability_zones)] : var.availability_zones[0]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}-${element(var.availability_zones, count.index)}-public-subnet"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "ig" {
  count = 1
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}-igw"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  count = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.environment}-public-route-table"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}

 resource "aws_route" "public_internet_gateway" {
  count = length(aws_route_table.public.*.id)
  route_table_id         = element(aws_route_table.public.*.id, count.index)
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.ig[0].id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  count = length(var.availability_zones)
  subnet_id      = element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, count.index)
  route_table_id = element(aws_route_table.public.*.id, count.index)
}
```

Query in aws_route_table_association.public section.

How do I attach private subnet of a particular az to a route table id. For example if i use 6 private subnets in tfvars, it creates atleast 2 private subnets in one az (ex: us-east-2a). How do i loop and attach 2 subnet from us-east-2a to one route table created for us-east-2a. Kind of map between multiple subnets in one az to route table in that az.

This is to attach each az nat gateway to that az subnet for routing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a route table per AZ, the route tables are linked to subnets. So, you can just create a single route table and then link all your public subnets to it:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.ig.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  count = var.public_subnet_count
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}
```

I've included the single route into the `route_table` to reduce the amount of code, so you can delete the `aws_route` resource if you use this.

[Edit]
Sorry I just noticed your mention of private subnets, but attaching route tables follows the same principle, and you don't need a NAT gateway per AZ either (that's expensive!) so you could route all private subnets through a single NAT gateway with one route table.

If you really want 4 NAT gateways, then you could do something like:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  count  = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.nat[count.index].id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  count = var.private_subnet_count

  subnet_id = aws_subnet.private[count.index].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[
    count.index % length(var.availability_zones)
  ].id
}
```

Since you already use the modulus (%) operator to distribute the subnets, I think you'll get the same result doing it this way.

Comment: Single NAT is not a best solution. If one az is down and if all instances are attached to the same nat, then instances in other az will also be impacted. AWS suggest to use one nat per az(at least 2 nat).

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated my answer to include an option in case multiple NATs are desired.